# Django/Apache & virtualenv on Ubuntu not using the right Python interpreter

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualenv

I'm running a small Django server on Ubuntu with `virtualenv`, `apache2` and `mod_wsgi`.

I have `virtualenv` created with `python3` on both windows and linux.  `pip --version` 
shows:

```
(env)lbr@irma-fr:/var/www/irmaweb/irmaweb$ pip --version
pip 7.0.3 from /var/www/irmaweb/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

It works fine on windows, but when deploying on my Ubuntu server i get the following error:

[image: Django Error]

The error is because Django create a new empty DB in `/var/www` instead of using the DB created by `./manage.py migrate` in my project root:

```
(env)lbr@irma-fr:/var/www/irmaweb/irmaweb$ ls -al /var/www
total 20
drwxrws---  5 lbr      www-data 4096 Jul  1 05:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root     root     4096 Jun 26 09:53 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    0 Jul  1 05:58 dev.db
```

But I think the root of the issue is because Django get called from `python2` as shown in the screenshot instead of getting called by `python3` as my `virtualenv` is configured for.

Here is below my `apache2` configuration:

```
(env)lbr@irma-fr:/var/www/irmaweb/irmaweb$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIDaemonProcess irmaweb python-path=/var/www/irmaweb/irmaweb:/var/www/irmaweb/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup irmaweb
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/irmaweb/irmaweb/irmaweb/wsgi.py
Alias /site_media/static/ /var/www/irmaweb/irmaweb/irmaweb/site_media/static/
```

So I guess I'm missing something! how to tell apache/wsgi to call python from my virtualenv folder:

```
(env)lbr@irma-fr:/var/www/irmaweb$ ls -al env/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lbr www-data       7 Jun 30 15:19 env/bin/python -> python3
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lbr www-data 4061272 Jun 30 15:19 env/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lbr www-data       7 Jun 30 15:19 env/bin/python3.4 -> python3
```

Instead of using the system python from /usr/bin ?

Comment: I had a similar issue before I realized that I needed to specifically compile `mod_wsgi` with the Python interpreter that I wanted to run the application with. I also had to include my compiled modules in my httpd.conf. Once I did that, it worked. Maybe I should include some of this info as an answer, but I don't know if it will help.

Comment: Can you post your wsgi script? That is where you activate your virtualenv

Comment: As others are pointing out, mod_wsgi is compiled for a specific Python major/minor version. You cannot force a mod_wsgi module compiled for Python 2.7 to use a Python 3.4 virtual environment. If using a system Python 3.4, then uninstall the system mod_wsgi package for Python 2.7 and install the Python 3.4 version instead. For Debian/Unbuntu systems the Python 3.4 variant for OS Python 3.4, has a '-py3' suffix on package name. If OS doesn't give Python 3.4 variant of mod_wsgi, you will need to build it from source code yourself against Python 3.4.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, um I totally just linked your library in my answer. Thank you for working on open source tools.

Comment: Yep. Saw your response and thanks for the detail. Just wanting to provide some extra confirmation.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, I uninstalled mod_wgsi and installed mod_wgi for py3.  But still the error remain.  
Here is what I did:  
1. sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-wsgi  
2. sudo apt-get autoremove  
3. sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

Comment: But do you still see Python 2 in the Python Path? That you were mixing Python versions may not be the cause of your issue, but it was still a problem that would have caused problems in other ways at some point.

Comment: Given that your SQLite database file seems to be 0 bytes in size. Have you tried removing it and starting over with doing a 'manage.py syncdb' to initialise it?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure this will be helpful, but I found it to be tricky the first time I set up Apache with `mod_wsgi` under a custom Python environment (3.4). I also had a similar problem making sure that Apache used my specific Python version.

Here are the steps I went through to get Apache and `mod_wsgi` working with a custom Python version. They may be helpful.

1.On a clean install of Ubuntu, I installed `apache2` and `apache2-dev`. Note: I did not install `mod_wsgi` from the repos.

2.I then downloaded this version of [mod_wsgi*](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.3.0.tar.gz) and compiled it against the specific Python3.4 I was using (which I had also previously built from source, but I don't think that should be necessary).

3.From inside the directory where I downloaded and unpacked `mod_wsgi`, I did the usual package-building, as root, with the added step of specifying the Python executable `mod_wsgi` should be compiled against:

```
   $ ./configure --with-python=/opt/python3.4/bin/python3.4
   $ make
   $ make install
```

After that, I configured the following files:

4.`/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

```
LoadModule dir_module   /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module   /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule mime_module  /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule wsgi_module  /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

ServerName localhost
WSGIPythonHome /location/of/virtualenv's/bin
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGILazyInitialization On
```

(That `mod_wsgi` above is the one that should have been built in the previous command.)

5.`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    Alias /media /var/www/django_media/
    Alias /static /var/www/django_static/

    <Directory /var/www/django_media>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/django_static>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    KeepAlive Off
    WSGIDaemonProcess site-name.com processes=2 threads=6 python-path=/var/www/location/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages:/var/www/location/env/bin:/var/www/location/location
    WSGIProcessGroup site-name.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/location/location/location/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/location/location>
        <Files wsgi.py>
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
    </Files>
    </Directory>

    LogLevel info
    LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    CustomLog log/location.log combined
    ErrorLog log/error/location.log
</VirtualHost>
```

6.Finally, I created a symlink to the default above:

```
$ ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

This may be useful as you try to figure out why your Apache version is not using the right Python? Personally, I would guess that `mod_wsgi` is to blame.

- The Mod wsgi archive linked above comes from here: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi

Answer (score 0):

To use python 3 interpreter with django  use following steps:

```
1) check python 3 path in your system by using -> which python3
output will be like this  ->  /usr/bin/python3
2) then create a virtual environment-> virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 project
it will create a virtual environment name as project
3)to activate it run- > . project/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by following @GrahamDumpleton's comment.

you don't need to rebuild mod_wsgi as a py3 package is available.  Here is what i did:

- remove mod_wsgi package and dependencies:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-wsgi
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  ```
- install mod_wsgi for python 3:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
  ```
- here is my apache configuration: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
  WSGIDaemonProcess irmaweb python-path=/var/www/irmaweb/irmaweb:/var/www/irmaweb/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages
  WSGIProcessGroup irmaweb
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/irmaweb/irmaweb/irmaweb/wsgi.py
  Alias /site_media/static/ /var/www/irmaweb/irmaweb/irmaweb/site_media/static/  
  ...
  ```
- then, restart apache:

  ```
  sudo service apache2 restart
  ```

I also add to specify the full path of the db file in my `settings.py`, and made a chmod 664 on it.